# tv-like noise b/w background removal from .jpg image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I'd like to remove this sort of tv-like noise from a `.jpg` image in order to get a `.png` image with transparent background.

[image: 1]

This is because I'll later need to overlay this picture over another one.
I've tried [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063070/overlay-a-smaller-image-on-a-larger-image-python-opencv),
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61641204/background-removal-using-opencv-python),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527769/removing-black-background-and-make-transparent-from-grabcut-output-in-python-ope), but all of them probably work only on black backgrounds.
I'm coding with `Python` and I thought OpenCV would help.
Do you have any idea? Thanks! :)

Comment: Maybe you can try [this approach](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/scipy/auto_examples/solutions/plot_fft_image_denoise.html) for denoising?

Comment: You could probably use edge detection to get the outline of the fish

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @MatteoPaiano such examples are given to the students in the `image-processing` courses to demonstrate the usefulness of the [median-filter](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) which works well in the case of salt and pepper noise, the one that you have in your image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Median Filter with Python and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427031/median-filter-with-python-and-opencv)

Answer (score 2):

Given that the noise is nearly exclusively black and white (i.e. desaturated) whereas the fish is colour, I would convert to [HSV colourspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and look to the Saturation channel for providing separation - the middle one in the row below:

[image]